# Lenovo Ideapad won't reboot or shutdown on Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, shutdown, lenovo, reboot

I have problem on my Lenovo Ideapad 100 with linux operating system. I install Ubuntu 15.04, it was stuck at Ubuntu logo at shutdown and show black screen when reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes opening a Terminal window and typing the following will help systems to shutdown and reboot again:

```
sudo update-grub
```

...enter password when prompted then try to shutdown again.

..or..

Install apmd by going into terminal and typing:

```
sudo apt-get install apmd
```

then edit the following file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

and add this line:

```
apm power_off=1
```

then restart by typing:

```
sudo reboot -f
```

and if that still doesn't work, try shutting down using:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

..or..

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

Comment: it doesn't help. I try it many time, but it still stuck at the logo when shutdown.

Comment: try the other options added to the list.